# How can I access to elements in dir(some_class) of PyQGIS without a dictionary in my code?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a QGIS plugin to search class methods in the different classes of PyQGIS. I used three widgets: 2 objects of type **QLineEdit** (for classes and class methods) and one **QTextBrowser** (for results). The snipped code is below:

```
.
.
.
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        text_search_class = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
        text_search_line = self.dlg.lineEdit2.text()

        dict = {'QgsVectorLayer' : dir(QgsVectorLayer) 
                'QgsRasterLayer' : dir(QgsRasterLayer),
                'QLineEdit'      : dir(QLineEdit)}

        if ( text_search_class in dict.keys() ) == True:

            idx = dict.keys().index(text_search_class)

            elements = getPat2(text_search_line, dict.values()[idx])

            n = len(elements)
            message = str(n) + " elements of '" + text_search_line + "' in " + text_search_class + "\n\n" 

            for i in range(n - 1):
                message += elements[i] + ', '

            if n != 0:
                message += elements[n - 1]

            txtBox = self.dlg.textFeedback
            txtBox.setText(message)
        else:
            message = "The chosen class does not exist"
            txtBox = self.dlg.textFeedback
            txtBox.setText(message)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

My issue is that I had to use a dictionary to get the list of methods from **dir(class)** (in my code I only use **QgsVectorLayer**, **QgsRasterLayer** and **QLineEdit**; but they are more than 1200) because, for example, the true list is for dir(QgsVectorLayer); not for dir('QgsVectorLayer') when I don't use the dictionary. My question is how can I access to elements in dir(some_class) of PyQGIS without a dictionary.

The next pictures show the execution of the plugin.

Without any text to search:

[image]

Searching by pending, set y max, respectively, in **QgsVectorLayer**, **QgsRasterLayer** and **QLineEdit**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058/convert-a-string-to-preexisting-variable-names/295113#295113

The keys words were in the title: "Convert a string to preexisting variable names".

My new code is now:

```
.
.
.
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        text_search_class = self.dlg.lineEdit.text()
        text_search_line = self.dlg.lineEdit2.text()

        try:

            elements = getPat2(text_search_line, dir(globals()[text_search_class]))

            n = len(elements)

            message = str(n) + " elements of '" + text_search_line + "' in " + text_search_class + "\n\n" 

            for i in range(n - 1):
                message += elements[i] + ', '

            if n != 0:
                message += elements[n - 1]

            txtBox = self.dlg.textFeedback
            txtBox.setText(message)

        except KeyError:
            message = "The chosen class does not exist"
            txtBox = self.dlg.textFeedback
            txtBox.setText(message)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()
        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
            # substitute with your code.
            pass
```

The next pictures show the execution of the plugin with the new classes extracted with **globals()** (without a dictionary):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an interesting plugin, and one I would have a lot of use for.

You can use the [**inspect module**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) to peek inside objects without using dictionaries. Better still, you can peek at the code, comments, argument lists and so on. The latter would be useful for a plugin like this ;-)

Here's a quick example to get you started.. in this case, I'm opening a file in GDAL and inspecting the datasource object returned, and listing any methods I find.

```
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr
from osgeo import gdal
from gdalconst import GA_ReadOnly

ds = gdal.Open("/tmp/hmap.tif",GA_ReadOnly)

import inspect
object = ds
for item in inspect.getmembers(object):
    # returns tuple (name,object)
    if inspect.ismethod(item[1]):
        print item
```

and the end result...

```
('AddBand', <bound method Dataset.AddBand of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('BeginAsyncReader', <bound method Dataset.BeginAsyncReader of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('BuildOverviews', <bound method Dataset.BuildOverviews of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('CreateMaskBand', <bound method Dataset.CreateMaskBand of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('EndAsyncReader', <bound method Dataset.EndAsyncReader of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('FlushCache', <bound method Dataset.FlushCache of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('GetDescription', <bound method Dataset.GetDescription of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
('GetDriver', <bound method Dataset.GetDriver of <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0xb15aea70> >>)
... and lots more
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very useful for searching the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295058/convert-a-string-to-preexisting-variable-names/295113#295113.

Comment: great! I hope you submit this plugin, it would be very useful!