# How can I print the text of help(some_method_class) in my QGIS plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a QGIS plugin to search classes and classes methods of QGIS. The **dir** equivalent option it was answered in:

[How can I access to elements in dir(some_class) of PyQGIS without a dictionary in my code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159324/how-can-i-access-to-elements-in-dirsome-class-of-pyqgis-without-a-dictionary-i/161945#161945)

As an example, the next image shows the search for methods with 'geo' pattern in **QgsVectorLayer** class and the result was as it expected.

[image]

When I tried out the equivalent **help** option at the plugin, with the next fixed example (see snipped code) for the 'geometryType' method of **QgsVectorLayer**, result it was always printed at the Python Console (not into the **QTextBrowser** object); as it can be observed at the next image.

```
.
.
.
    def getClasses(self):

        if self.dlg.checkBox.isChecked() == False:
.
.
.
        else:

            message = help(QgsVectorLayer.geometryType)
            txtBox = self.dlg.textFeedback
            txtBox.setText(message)

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
.
.
.
```

Other arbitrary messages were printed as I expected so, it was pointed out that this part of the code works well.

[image]

My question is:

There is any option to redirect the text of the help command to the **QTextBrowser** object or it is impossible?

**Editing Note**

I did a search based at the links supplied by **Joseph**:

[Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

[Unable to restore stdout to original (only to terminal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777152/unable-to-restore-stdout-to-original-only-to-terminal)

and I can build this code:

```
import sys

#save a reference to the Python Console of QGIS before reassignment
oldstdout = sys.stdout

#open an arbitrary file in disc to reassign the standard output
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')

#write to the open file
print help(QgsVectorLayer.geometryType)

#force the flush to the open file
sys.stdout.flush()

#reassign the standard output to the Python Console
sys.stdout = oldstdout
```

It works; as it can be observed at the next image (and the Python Console can be used again as standard output). However, I would like to improve the code by using a tempfile in memory before writing it to the **QTextBrowser**.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps these posts might help: [How to capture output of Python's interpreter and show in a Text widget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356336/how-to-capture-output-of-pythons-interpreter-and-show-in-a-text-widget); [How to Redirect a Python Console output to a QTextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859256/how-to-redirect-a-python-console-output-to-a-qtextbox)

Comment: Does a print statement on your message variable show nothing?

Comment: @artwork21 The print statement with the name 'message', as output of **help** command, is printing on the Python Console  instead of **QTextBrowser**. However, output of **dir** command can be printed on this Qt Object because it is a list of elements. I would like to redirect the standard output of help command (Python Console) to  the **QTextBrowser**.

Comment: @Joseph Thanks a lot for the links. I'll see them later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a [temporary file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html), as reassignment of the standard output (Python Console), next code works.

```
...
import sys, os
import tempfile as tmpf
...
        else:

            #save a reference to the Python Console of QGIS before reassignment
            oldstdout = sys.stdout

            #creating a temporary file
            file = tmpf.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)

            file_name = file.name

            #reassigning the standard output to temporary file
            sys.stdout = file

            #printing to temporary file
            help(QgsVectorLayer.geometryType)

            #force the flush to temporary file
            sys.stdout.flush()

            file.close()

            #reassigning the standard output to the Python Console
            sys.stdout = oldstdout

            #opening temporary file
            tmp_file = open(file_name, 'r')

            data = tmp_file.read()

            #writing to QTextBrowser
            txtBox = self.dlg.textFeedback
            txtBox.setText(data)

            tmp_file.close()

            #erasing temporary file
            os.unlink(file.name)

    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""
...
```

as it can be observed at the next image:

[image]